# php/mysql: development on Win, deployment on Linux

Tags: php, windows, xampp

A possibly "silly" question.
Would I possibly run into any problems (incompatibilities) deploying eg.: on Centos/Apache (php5/MySQL5) a project developed on Win desktop (WAMP/XAMPP - php5/MySQL5).

I found some answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233791/looking-for-lightweight-php-stack-for-development-on-windows) on Stack. 
But it does not address all my concerns.
If I missed any thread - I appreciate a link.

Comment: It completely depends on what your php is doing. Which modules are you using?

Comment: Also you need to be careful how you name your files. Linux is case sensitive where Windows it isn't. I.e. Config.php is the same as config.php on Windows but in Linux thay can be two separate files. So careful when naming and including files.

Comment: adam - standard "run-off-the-mill" php installation, nothing extra

Comment: daniels - I run into it this problem once in a very painful way - thank you very much for your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple PHP application, you shouldn't have any problems.  I have done this many times.

There are a few things to keep in mind when developing though, the three biggest I have run into being:

-Make sure your PHP extensions are the same on both machines.  You can see this in `phpinfo()`

-Avoid hard coded file paths.  If you have any, you will need to check for both a Windows and a Linux location

-Keep file case consistent, Linux is case sensitive while Windows is not, so a file that is found in Windows will not be in Linux if the case is not consistent